# MVC Razor View update Form on SelectedIndexChange

Tags: ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, selectedindexchanged

I have a form in a View that brings together a number of  pieces of information (address, telephone etc). All these elements are wrapped up in a view model. There is one section that asks the user to select a county. On selection, I want to be able to show a price based on the county selected.

I came across the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204220/asp-net-mvc-selected-index-changed-ajax-actionlink) which is close to what I want, but it looks like the action submits the form to a 'change controller'. I naively need to be able to basically call two controllers - one onSelectedChange and the other onSubmit. I'm pretty sure ya can't do this!

Here' what I'm after:

```
@model ViewOrder

@using (Html.BeginForm("Order", "Home"))
{
    @* - textboxes et al - *@

    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Counties, 
          new SelectList(Model.Counties, "CountyId", "County"), 
          new { @class = "form-control  input-sm" })
    </p>
    <p>
        @* - £Price result of dropdown list selection and 
        add to View Model to add to sub total - *@
    </p>

    <input type="submit" text = "submit"/>
}
```

I'm very new to MVC - Could do this easily in webforms (but I'm sticking with MVC!) There must be some form of Ajax action that would allow this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a problem with you `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method. `Model.Counties` is a complex object (with properties `CountyId` and `County`) but you cannot bind a `<select>` (or any control) to a complex object, only a value type. Your model needs a property (say) `public int SelectedCountry { get; set; }` and then `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCountry, new SelectList(Model.Counties, "CountyId", "County"), ...)`

To display the price, you need to handle the `.change` event of the dropdown, pass the selected value to a controller method, and update the DOM.

Script (based on the property being `SelectedCountry`)

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetPrice", "yourControllerName")';
$('#SelectedCountry').change(function() {
   $.getJSON(url, { ID: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
     // do something with the data returned by the method, for example
     $('#someElement').text(data);
   });
});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult GetPrice(int ID)
{
  // ID contains the value of the selected country
  var data = "some price to return";
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Wow! That worked a treat (not that I had any doubts!). I obviously have a lot to learn, but I now have another step up the ladder.